# how to transpose in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have

```
select *
from A a
     left outer join B b on b.ID in (1,2,3/*and possibly any numbers*/)
```

and so I get (`Ax - A's xth row, Bx - B's xth row`):

```
A1 B1
A1 B2
A1 B3
A2 B1
...
```

And what I want is this:

```
A1 B1 B2 B3
A2 B1 B2 B3
```

So that there is dynamic number of columns. What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using [Pivots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28SQL.105%29.aspx). 
The below link might help you. It contains 4-5 different solutions.

[Tranpose in SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/318546/Transpose-Rows-in-SQL-Server)